# ending up with outputs of null & methods that don't run

Tags: java, arrays

Trying to create a magic square game for my Java class. My first go through came up with the following code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class square {

static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String mainMenuUser = null;

    while(mainMenuUser != "quit"){
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(" Welcome to Magic Square! ");
    System.out.println("--------------------------");
    System.out.println("Type any of the following:");
    System.out.println("--------------------------");
    System.out.println("Rules     (Displays Rules)");
    System.out.println("Play     (Starts The Game)");
    System.out.println("Quit      (Quits The Game)");
    System.out.println("--------------------------");

    System.out.print("Your Choice: ");
    mainMenuUser = scanner.next();

    switch(mainMenuUser.toLowerCase()){
    case "rules": 
        rules();
        break;
    case "play": 
        play(null); 
        break;
    case "quit": 
        break;
    default: 
        System.out.println("You Typed something wrong."); 
        break;
        }

    }
}
public static void rules(){
    System.out.println("The Rules Are: ");
    System.out.println("1: All numbers must be different");
    System.out.println("       It will tell you if you have duplicates.");
    System.out.println("2: All numbers must add up to be the same Left to right");
    System.out.println("3: All numbers must add up to be the same Top to Bottom");
    System.out.println("4: All numbers must add up to be the same Diagonal Top left to Bottom Right");
    System.out.println("4.A: All numbers must add up to be the same Diagonal Top Right to Bottom Left");
}
public static void play(int[] rowTotalsLR){
    int userGridSize;
    int tempMultiply;

    System.out.println("Please Enter a number for the size of the grid.");
    System.out.println("This number will be squared");

    userGridSize = scanner.nextInt();
    tempMultiply = userGridSize * userGridSize;
    System.out.println("Your Grid Size Will Be: " + tempMultiply);
    takeInGridNums(userGridSize, rowTotalsLR);
}
public static void takeInGridNums(int userGridSize, int[] rowTotalsLR){
    int gridRows = 0, gridColumns = 0;

    int[][] gridNums = new int[userGridSize][userGridSize];

    int tempSize = gridNums.length;

    int tempSizeFull = tempSize * tempSize;

    for(int temp = 0; temp != tempSizeFull; temp++){
        if(gridColumns == gridNums.length){gridRows++; gridColumns = 0;}
        System.out.println("Please Eneter A number for Grid Position: " + gridRows + " , " + gridColumns);
        gridNums[gridRows][gridColumns] = scanner.nextInt();
        gridColumns++;
    }

    leftToRight(tempSizeFull, gridNums, tempSizeFull);
    topToBottom(tempSizeFull, gridNums, tempSizeFull);
    diagonalLeftToRight(userGridSize, gridNums, tempSizeFull);
    diagonalRightToLeft(userGridSize, gridNums, tempSizeFull);
    outputResultsOfGame(tempSizeFull, gridNums, rowTotalsLR, null, tempSizeFull, tempSizeFull, tempSizeFull, null, null);
}
public static void leftToRight(int userGridSize, int[][] gridNums, int tempSizeFull){

    int tempGridColumns = 0, totalLeftToRight = 0, tempPoint, tempTotal = 0, tempGridRows = 0;
    int[] rowTotalsLR = new int[userGridSize];

    for(int temp = 0; temp != tempSizeFull; temp++){

        if(tempGridColumns == gridNums.length){
            rowTotalsLR[tempGridRows] = totalLeftToRight;
            tempGridRows++; 
            tempGridColumns = 0; 
            tempTotal = 0;
            totalLeftToRight = 0;
            }

         tempPoint = gridNums[tempGridRows][tempGridColumns];
         totalLeftToRight = tempTotal + tempPoint;
         tempTotal = totalLeftToRight;
         tempGridColumns++;
    }
}
public static void topToBottom(int userGridSize, int[][] gridNums, int tempSizeFull){

    int tempGridColumns = 0, totalRightToLeft = 0, tempPoint = 0, tempTotal = 0, tempGridRows = 0;
    int[] rowTotalsRL = new int[userGridSize];

    for(int temp = 0; temp != tempSizeFull; temp++){

        if(tempGridRows == gridNums.length){
            rowTotalsRL[tempGridRows] = totalRightToLeft;
            tempGridColumns++; 
            tempGridRows = 0; 
            tempTotal = 0;
            totalRightToLeft = 0;
            }

         tempPoint = gridNums[tempGridRows][tempGridColumns];
         totalRightToLeft = tempTotal + tempPoint;
         tempTotal = totalRightToLeft;
         tempGridRows++;

    }

}
public static void diagonalLeftToRight(int userGridSize, int[][] gridNums, int tempSizeFull){

    int totalDagLeftToRight = 0, tempPoint = 0, tempTotal = 0;
    int[] totalsDagLR = new int[userGridSize];

    for(int temp = 0; temp < tempSizeFull; temp++){
    //for(int temp = 0; temp != gridNums.length; temp++){
        if(temp == gridNums.length){break;}
         tempPoint = gridNums[temp][temp];
         totalDagLeftToRight = tempTotal + tempPoint;
         tempTotal = totalDagLeftToRight;
         totalsDagLR[temp] = tempTotal;

    }
}
public static void diagonalRightToLeft(int userGridSize, int[][] gridNums, int tempSizeFull){

    int totalDagLeftToRight = 0, tempPoint = 0, tempTotal = 0, tempUp = 0, tempDown = gridNums.length-1;
    int[] totalsDagRL = new int[userGridSize];

    for(int temp = 0; temp != gridNums.length; temp++){

         tempPoint = gridNums[tempUp][tempDown];
         totalDagLeftToRight = tempTotal + tempPoint;
         tempTotal = totalDagLeftToRight;
         totalsDagRL[temp] = tempTotal;

    }
}
public static void outputResultsOfGame(int userGridSize, int[][] gridNums, int[] rowTotalsLR, int[] rowTotalsRL, int gridRows, int gridColumns, int tempSizeFull, int[] totalsDagLR, long[] totalsDagRL){
    System.out.println("Your Numbers Entered Were: ");
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(gridNums));
    System.out.println("The Totals of the Rows Are: ");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(rowTotalsLR));
    System.out.println("The Total of the Columns Are: ");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(rowTotalsRL));
    System.out.println("The Total of The Top left to Bottom Right Diagonal is: ");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(totalsDagLR));
    System.out.println("The Total of The Top Right to Bottom Left Diagonal is: ");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(totalsDagRL));

    }
}
```

My problem with that is the outputs end with `null` for all of the math methods. After seeing that I decided I need to revise my code and make it more organized. Which I did below;

EDITED THIS CODE 2/21/15 10:29PM EST

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class testingChanges {

static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String mainMenuUser = "";
    int userGridSize = 0, gridRows = 0, gridColumns = 0, totalRightToLeft = 0, tempGridColumns = 0, totalLeftToRight = 0, tempPoint = 0, tempTotal = 0, tempGridRows = 0, totalDagLeftToRight = 0;
    int[][] gridNums = new int[userGridSize][userGridSize];
    int tempSize = gridNums.length, tempUp = 0, tempDown = gridNums.length-1;
    int tempMultiply = userGridSize * userGridSize;
    int[] rowTotalsLR = new int[userGridSize];
    int[] rowTotalsRL = new int[userGridSize];
    int[] totalsDagLR = new int[userGridSize];
    int[] totalsDagRL = new int[userGridSize];

    while(mainMenuUser != "quit"){
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(" Welcome to Magic Square! ");
    System.out.println("--------------------------");
    System.out.println("Type any of the following:");
    System.out.println("--------------------------");
    System.out.println("Rules     (Displays Rules)");
    System.out.println("Play     (Starts The Game)");
    System.out.println("Quit      (Quits The Game)");
    System.out.println("--------------------------");

    System.out.print("Your Choice: ");
    mainMenuUser = scanner.next();

    switch(mainMenuUser.toLowerCase()){
    case "rules": 
        rules();
        break;
    case "play": 
        play(userGridSize, tempMultiply, rowTotalsLR, tempGridColumns, gridNums, tempGridRows, totalLeftToRight, tempTotal, tempPoint, gridColumns, gridRows, rowTotalsRL, totalRightToLeft, totalDagLeftToRight, totalsDagLR, totalsDagRL, tempUp, tempDown); 
        break;
    case "quit": 
        break;
    default: 
        System.out.println("You Typed something wrong."); 
        break;
        }

    }
}
public static void rules(){
    System.out.println("The Rules Are: ");
    System.out.println("1: All numbers must be different");
    System.out.println("       It will tell you if you have duplicates.");
    System.out.println("2: All numbers must add up to be the same Left to right");
    System.out.println("3: All numbers must add up to be the same Top to Bottom");
    System.out.println("4: All numbers must add up to be the same Diagonal Top left to Bottom Right");
    System.out.println("4.A: All numbers must add up to be the same Diagonal Top Right to Bottom Left");
}
public static void play(int userGridSize, int tempMultiply, int[] rowTotalsLR, int tempGridColumns, int[][] gridNums, int tempGridRows, int totalLeftToRight, int tempTotal, int tempPoint, int gridColumns, int gridRows, int[] rowTotalsRL, int totalRightToLeft, int totalDagLeftToRight, int[] totalsDagLR, int[] totalsDagRL, int tempUp, int tempDown){       
    System.out.println("Please Enter a number for the size of the grid.");
    System.out.println("This number will be squared");

    userGridSize = scanner.nextInt();
    gridNums = new int[userGridSize][userGridSize];
    tempMultiply = userGridSize * userGridSize;
    System.out.println("Your Grid Size Will Be: " + tempMultiply);
    takeInGridNums(gridColumns, gridRows, gridNums, tempGridColumns, tempGridRows, totalLeftToRight, rowTotalsLR, tempTotal, tempPoint, rowTotalsRL, totalRightToLeft, totalsDagLR, totalDagLeftToRight, totalsDagRL, tempUp, tempDown, tempDown);
}
public static void takeInGridNums(int gridColumns, int gridRows, int[][] gridNums, int tempGridColumns, int tempGridRows, int totalLeftToRight, int[] rowTotalsLR, int tempTotal, int tempPoint, int[] rowTotalsRL, int totalRightToLeft, int[] totalsDagLR, int totalDagLeftToRight, int[] totalsDagRL, int tempUp, int tempDown, int tempMultiply){
    System.out.println("INSIDE OF TAKE IN");
    System.out.println(tempMultiply);
    for(int temp = 0; temp != tempMultiply; temp++){
        if(gridColumns == gridNums.length){gridRows++; gridColumns = 0;}
        System.out.println("Please Eneter A number for Grid Position: " + gridRows + " , " + gridColumns);
        gridNums[gridRows][gridColumns] = scanner.nextInt();
        gridColumns++;
    }

    leftToRight(tempGridColumns, tempMultiply, gridNums, tempGridRows, totalLeftToRight, rowTotalsLR, tempTotal, tempPoint);
    topToBottom(tempGridRows, tempMultiply, gridNums, rowTotalsRL, totalRightToLeft, tempGridColumns, tempTotal, tempPoint);
    diagonalLeftToRight(tempMultiply, gridNums, tempPoint, totalDagLeftToRight, tempTotal, totalsDagLR);
    diagonalRightToLeft(gridNums, tempPoint, totalDagLeftToRight, tempTotal, totalsDagRL, tempUp, tempDown);
    outputResultsOfGame(gridNums, rowTotalsLR, rowTotalsRL, totalsDagLR, totalsDagRL);
}
public static void leftToRight(int tempMultiply, int tempGridColumns, int[][] gridNums, int tempGridRows, int totalLeftToRight, int[] rowTotalsLR, int tempTotal, int tempPoint){
    for(int temp = 0; temp != tempMultiply; temp++){

        if(tempGridColumns == gridNums.length){
            rowTotalsLR[tempGridRows] = totalLeftToRight;
            tempGridRows++; 
            tempGridColumns = 0; 
            tempTotal = 0;
            totalLeftToRight = 0;
            }

         tempPoint = gridNums[tempGridRows][tempGridColumns];
         totalLeftToRight = tempTotal + tempPoint;
         tempTotal = totalLeftToRight;
         tempGridColumns++;
    }
}
public static void topToBottom(int tempMultiply, int tempGridRows, int[][] gridNums, int[] rowTotalsRL, int totalRightToLeft, int tempGridColumns, int tempTotal, int tempPoint){
    for(int temp = 0; temp != tempMultiply; temp++){

        if(tempGridRows == gridNums.length){
            rowTotalsRL[tempGridRows] = totalRightToLeft;
            tempGridColumns++; 
            tempGridRows = 0; 
            tempTotal = 0;
            totalRightToLeft = 0;
            }

         tempPoint = gridNums[tempGridRows][tempGridColumns];
         totalRightToLeft = tempTotal + tempPoint;
         tempTotal = totalRightToLeft;
         tempGridRows++;

    }

}
public static void diagonalLeftToRight(int tempMultiply, int[][] gridNums, int tempPoint, int totalDagLeftToRight, int tempTotal, int[] totalsDagLR){
    for(int temp = 0; temp < tempMultiply; temp++){
    //for(int temp = 0; temp != gridNums.length; temp++){
        if(temp == gridNums.length){break;}
         tempPoint = gridNums[temp][temp];
         totalDagLeftToRight = tempTotal + tempPoint;
         tempTotal = totalDagLeftToRight;
         totalsDagLR[temp] = tempTotal;

    }
}
public static void diagonalRightToLeft(int[][] gridNums, int tempPoint, int totalDagLeftToRight, int tempTotal, int[] totalsDagRL, int tempUp, int tempDown){
    for(int temp = 0; temp != gridNums.length; temp++){

         tempPoint = gridNums[tempUp][tempDown];
         totalDagLeftToRight = tempTotal + tempPoint;
         tempTotal = totalDagLeftToRight;
         totalsDagRL[temp] = tempTotal;

    }
}
public static void outputResultsOfGame(int[][] gridNums, int[] rowTotalsLR, int[] rowTotalsRL, int[] totalsDagLR, int[] totalsDagRL){
    System.out.println("Your Numbers Entered Were: ");
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(gridNums));
    System.out.println("The Totals of the Rows Are: ");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(rowTotalsLR));
    System.out.println("The Total of the Columns Are: ");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(rowTotalsRL));
    System.out.println("The Total of The Top left to Bottom Right Diagonal is: ");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(totalsDagLR));
    System.out.println("The Total of The Top Right to Bottom Left Diagonal is: ");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(totalsDagRL));

}
```

}

Then that code ends up with the `takeInGridNums(..);` method not even asking my for my inputs. I know it may be weird that all of my variables are in main but I was just trying to troubleshoot and make things a more simple by having all my needed variables there and just pass them into my methods that way. I was also trying to avoid using global variables. I did use one for my scanner because that is just a whole lot easier. Any help getting either of these two codes to work would be really appreciated.

Comment: Try setting String mainMenuUser = ""; instead of null.

Comment: @GregoryBasior Just did as you suggested and no change in outputs, sorry.

Comment: The loop for(int temp = 0; temp != tempSizeFull; temp++){ never runs because tempSizeFull = 0.

Comment: @GregoryBasior I changed the tempSizeFull to tempMultiply becuase in the play() method I actually set the size to tempMultiply. But when it runs the takeInForNums method it says my tempMultiply variable is blank, which it shouldn't be because I actually output with it inside of the play() method.

Comment: Can you show me the exact change you made.

Comment: It looks like value of rowTotalsLR is null since you call play(null)

Comment: @GregoryBasior on line 72 in testing changes it now reads:   for(int temp = 0; temp != tempMultiply; temp++)

Instead of what the Original post says on line 72.

Comment: The play(null) call was in the previous version of his code, he fixed that issue.

Comment: @AndréFecteau is that inside the takeInGridNums method?  Because I do not see a reference to tempMultiply inside of that method.

Comment: @GregoryBasior Yes inside of the takeInGridNums, sorry I had not updated it in the original post. will do that now.

Comment: Also, when the user enters the new grid number, shouldn't you recreate the array:  gridNums = new int[userGridSize][userGridSize];  It looks like you need to update all of the sizes of the arrays once you get user input.

Comment: @GregoryBasior honestly, my current situation is I learned Java in about 3 days because I was put in an Advanced Java class at my current college because when I transferred there I had taken an intro C++ course already which they counted as their intro Java course. So I am still pretty new. If you think it would be wise to recreate the array I will do so lol

Comment: An easy way around this is to use ArrayList instead of array because you do not need to know the size beforehand. For a multidimensional array, you can use ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> instead of int[][].  If you were to change your int arrays to ArrayLists, you would have no issue with the sizing.

Comment: is the sizing what is causing a lot of issues with the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After rewriting the whole code I have finally made a finished product. Basically I got rid of all of the passing by reference and created instance variables. I came to this decision after emailing my Java teacher asking if using instance variables was OK. She confirmed and said I should be using instance variables for this project. This caused me to decide to write the whole program over again created this below. Thank you for everyone that tried to help but my code before was just way too much of a mess to ever make sense.

Current working program:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class squareAgain {

static Scanner scan =  new Scanner(System.in);
static int[][] userSquare = new int[0][0];
static int[] mathLRTotals = new int[0], mathTBTotals = new int[0], mathDLRTotals = new int[1], mathDRLTotals = new int[1];
static String userMenuInput = "presetByProgrammer";
static int totalElements = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    while(userMenuInput != "quit"){

        mainMenu();
        System.out.print("Your Choice: ");
        userMenuInput = scan.next();

        switch(userMenuInput.toLowerCase()){
        case "rules": 
            menuOptionRules();
            break;
        case "play": 
            menuOptionPlay(); 
            break;
        case "quit":
            System.out.println("Now Quitting.");
            userMenuInput = "quit";
            break;
        default: 
            System.out.println("You Typed something wrong."); 
            break;
            }

    }
}
private static void mainMenu(){
    System.out.println(" Welcome to Magic Square! ");
    System.out.println("--------------------------");
    System.out.println("Type any of the following:");
    System.out.println("--------------------------");
    System.out.println("Rules     (Displays Rules)");
    System.out.println("Play     (Starts The Game)");
    System.out.println("Quit      (Quits The Game)");
    System.out.println("--------------------------");
}
private static void menuOptionRules(){
    System.out.println("The Rules Are: ");
    System.out.println("1: All numbers must be different");
    System.out.println("       It will tell you if you have duplicates.");
    System.out.println("2: All numbers must add up to be the same Left to right");
    System.out.println("3: All numbers must add up to be the same Top to Bottom");
    System.out.println("4: All numbers must add up to be the same Diagonal Top left to Bottom Right");
    System.out.println("4.A: All numbers must add up to be the same Diagonal Top Right to Bottom Left");
}
private static void menuOptionPlay(){
    getUserInputs();
    mathLR();
    mathTB();
    mathDLR();
    mathDRL();
    outputs();  
}
private static void getUserInputs(){

    System.out.println("Thank You For Playing.");
    System.out.print("Please Enter A Size For Your Square: ");
    int userSquareSizeInput = scan.nextInt();
    userSquare = new int[userSquare.length+userSquareSizeInput][userSquare.length+userSquareSizeInput];
    System.out.println("Array Length is now: " + userSquare.length);
    totalElements = userSquareSizeInput * userSquareSizeInput;
    System.out.println("This Means You Will Have " + totalElements + " elements." );
    System.out.println();

    int tempForGridInputRow = 0, tempForGridInputCol = 0;
    for(int temp = 0; temp != totalElements; temp++){
        if(tempForGridInputCol == userSquare.length){tempForGridInputRow++; tempForGridInputCol = 0;}
        System.out.print("Please Eneter A number for Grid Position: " + tempForGridInputRow + " , " + tempForGridInputCol + ": ");
        userSquare[tempForGridInputRow][tempForGridInputCol] = scan.nextInt();
        tempForGridInputCol++;
    }
    System.out.println();
}
private static void mathLR(){
    mathLRTotals = new int[mathLRTotals.length+userSquare.length];

    int tempForGridInputRow = 0, tempForGridInputCol = 0, tempElement = 0, tempTotal = 0;
    for(int temp = 0; temp < totalElements; temp++){
        tempElement = tempElement + userSquare[tempForGridInputRow][tempForGridInputCol];
        tempTotal = tempElement;
        tempForGridInputCol++;

        if(tempForGridInputCol == userSquare.length){
            mathLRTotals[tempForGridInputRow] = tempTotal; 
            tempForGridInputRow++; 
            tempForGridInputCol = 0;
            tempTotal = 0;
            tempElement = 0;
            }
    }
}
private static void mathTB(){
    mathTBTotals = new int[mathTBTotals.length+userSquare.length];

    int tempForGridInputRow = 0, tempForGridInputCol = 0, tempElement = 0, tempTotal = 0;
    for(int temp = 0; temp < totalElements; temp++){            
        tempElement = tempElement + userSquare[tempForGridInputRow][tempForGridInputCol];
        tempTotal = tempElement;
        tempForGridInputRow++;
        if(tempForGridInputRow == userSquare.length){
            mathTBTotals[tempForGridInputCol] = tempTotal; 
            tempForGridInputRow = 0; 
            tempForGridInputCol++;
            tempTotal = 0;
            tempElement = 0;
            }
    }
}
private static void mathDLR(){
    int tempElement = 0;

    for(int temp = 0; temp != userSquare.length; temp ++){

        tempElement = tempElement + userSquare[temp][temp];
        mathDLRTotals[0] = tempElement;
    }
}
private static void mathDRL(){
    int tempForGridInputRow = 0, tempForGridInputCol = userSquare.length-1, tempElement = 0;

    for(int temp = 0; temp != userSquare.length; temp ++){

        tempElement = tempElement + userSquare[tempForGridInputRow][tempForGridInputCol];
        mathDRLTotals[0] = tempElement;

        tempForGridInputRow++;
        tempForGridInputCol--;
    }
}
private static void outputs(){
    System.out.println("You Entered " + userSquare.length + " As your grid length and height");
    System.out.println("This means there was " + totalElements + " elements in your square.");
    System.out.println("Here is what you entered: ");
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(userSquare));
    System.out.println("The totals for each row are: ");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(mathLRTotals));
    System.out.println("The totals for each column are: ");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(mathTBTotals));
    System.out.println("The total of the Left to Right Diagonal: ");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(mathDLRTotals));
    System.out.println("The total of Right to Left Diagonal: ");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(mathDRLTotals));
    System.out.println();

    String tempYesForLR = "setByProgrammer";
    int tempCompareLR = mathLRTotals[0];
    for(int temp = 0; temp != mathLRTotals.length; temp++){
        if(tempCompareLR == mathLRTotals[temp]){tempYesForLR = "true";}else{tempYesForLR = "false"; break;}
    }

    String tempYesForTB = "setByProgrammer";
    int tempCompareTB = mathTBTotals[0];
    for(int temp = 0; temp != mathTBTotals.length; temp++){
        if(tempCompareTB == mathTBTotals[temp]){tempYesForTB = "true";}else{tempYesForTB = "false"; break;}
    }

    Boolean tempForYesDag = false;
    if(mathDLRTotals[0] == mathDRLTotals[0]){tempForYesDag = true;}

    if(tempYesForLR == tempYesForTB == tempForYesDag){
        System.out.println("All of the rows added up to be: " + mathLRTotals[0]);
        System.out.println("You created a Perfect Square!");
        System.out.println();
        }
    else{
        System.out.println("Your rows didn't add up to the same number.");
        System.out.println("Review what you entered and try again!");
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Just FYI, you are not using instance variables in this program, you are using static variables or class level variables.

Answer (score 0):

In your second set of code, your `takeInGridNums(..)` method is being called, but you're creating a grid that is `tempSizeFull` large. Your `tempSizeFill` variable is 0, however, because you're basing it on `userGridSize` within your main and that is initialized to 0. When a user types in the grid size they want, `tempSizeFull` isn't automatically updated, so your `for` loop is being skipped.

So instead of:

```
userGridSize = scanner.nextInt();
tempMultiply = userGridSize * userGridSize;
System.out.println("Your Grid Size Will Be: " + tempMultiply);
takeInGridNums(gridColumns, tempSizeFull, gridRows, gridNums, tempGridColumns, tempGridRows, totalLeftToRight, rowTotalsLR, tempTotal, tempPoint, rowTotalsRL, totalRightToLeft, totalsDagLR, totalDagLeftToRight, totalsDagRL, tempUp, tempDown);`
```

Try something like:

```
userGridSize = scanner.nextInt();
tempMultiply = userGridSize * userGridSize;
System.out.println("Your Grid Size Will Be: " + tempMultiply);
gridNums = new int[userGridSize][userGridSize];
int tempSize = gridNums.length;
tempSizeFull = tempSize * tempSize;
takeInGridNums(gridColumns, tempSizeFull, gridRows, gridNums, tempGridColumns, tempGridRows, totalLeftToRight, rowTotalsLR, tempTotal, tempPoint, rowTotalsRL, totalRightToLeft, totalsDagLR, totalDagLeftToRight, totalsDagRL, tempUp, tempDown);
```

Comment: Thank you, I have reflected a similar change in the original post to the code you are talking about. I now am able to enter numbers for my array but I end up receiving a Array Index out of Bounds error.

Comment: Its the same issue. All your temp variables are relying on the userGridSize. You might want to move those variables into your play method, and then give them their value after the user inputs their grid size.

Answer (score 0):

If you make the following changes:

```
  ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> gridNums = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
  ArrayList<Integer> rowTotalsLR = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> rowTotalsRL = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> totalsDagLR = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> totalsDagRL = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

The loop would then look like:
     int numCols = (int)Math.sqrt(tempMultiply);
     for(int temp = 0; temp != tempMultiply; temp++){
            if(gridColumns == numCols){gridRows++; gridColumns = 0;}
            System.out.println("Please Eneter A number for Grid Position: " + gridRows + " , " + gridColumns);
            gridNums.get(gridRows).add(scanner.nextInt());
            gridColumns++;
        }

Then you would make similar changes to account for changing from arrays to ArrayList